# Реализация отзывов через оценку конкретных действий

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Всем привет. Проект на Laravel. Делаю отзывы, необходимо, чтобы пользователь ставил 3 оценки по параметрам (качество, доставка, общение), а из этих 3 параметров высчитывалось среднее арифметическое, которое и является основной оценкой, по которой будет фильтрация отзывов.

Как правильно сделать: отдельный столбец `final_rating` или же каждый раз это высчитывать? По кол-ву данных легче сделать через вычисляемое, по операционной составляющей через отдельный столбец.

Comment: если отзывов будет много, то надо по расчетному рейтингу сделать индекс. зы: а вместо среднего просто сумму брать, ибо от деления на 3 ничего не изменится, но можно остаться в целых числах, если рейтинги целочисленные

Answer (score 1):

Если эти три параметра в будущем не будут меняться - то лучше сделать через отдельный столбец. Меньше нагрузка на базу, а результат тот же.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал через отдельную таблицу с отзывами, а среднее арифметическое обрабатывал раз в сутки или часы через cron, и записывал в столбец рейтинга к существу, которому ставим рейтинг.

Для примера у нас есть таблица с товарами, где поле `rate` это средне арифметическое. И Таблица с отзывами - 
   `text, rate1, rate2, rate3, item_id`   . Где `item_id`, это ключ по которому мы будем искать продукты.

Если же поставить индексирование на таблицу с отзывами, то время записи будет занимать больше времени.

Comment: рейтинг не у отдельной сущности, а у самих отзывов. их самих и фильтровать надо